# Оптимизация алгоритма на Python для строки

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

*Всех с праздником*! Я создал небольшой алгоритм, который из **строки** длиной n показывает **наибольший возможный отрезок**, где одинаковые буквы встречаются не более k раз. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
n,k = map(int, input().split()) ## n - длина строки, k - максимальное количество букв в отрезке
l = input() ## сама строка длиной в n
ans = []
l1 = list(set(l))
l1.sort()

for f in range(len(l)):
    l2 = [0] * len(l1)

    s = 0
    for i in range(f, len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l2)):

            if l[i] == l1[j]:
                l2[j] += 1
        if max(l2) > k:
            break
        s += 1
    ans.append(s)

print(max(ans), end = ' ')
print(ans.index(max(ans))+1)
```

Но программа выполняется очень долго, особенно если n больше 10000. Как можно оптимизировать данную систему?

Comment: Похоже на задачу про скользящее окно.

Comment: а что у вас здесь `l = input()`?

Comment: @SergFS, это как раз таки строка, которая содержит латинские буквы от a до z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше решение в худшем случае работает за куб от длины строки. Если учесть ограниченный алфавит, то время работы - квадрат длины строки на размер алфавита.

Задачу можно решить за линейное время. Для этого будем поддерживать пару индексов `i <= j` и счётчики символов на полуинтервале `[i, j)`. Когда интервал расширяется (`j += 1`) соответствующий счётчик увеличивается на единицу. Если он превысил порог `k`, двигаем `i` (`i += 1`). Соответствующие счётчики уменьшаем. Останавливаемся когда превышение порога исчезло. Каждую найденную пару `(i, j)` публикуем. По окончании цикла публикуем последнюю пару `(i, len(s))`. Снаружи от цикла ищем самую длинную пару.

```
import collections


def spans(k, s):
    counter = collections.Counter()

    i = 0
    for j, c in enumerate(s):
        yield j - i, i + 1
        counter[c] += 1
        while counter[c] > k:
            counter[s[i]] -= 1
            i += 1
    yield len(s) - i, i + 1


def main():
    _, k = map(int, input().split()) ## _ - длина строки, k - максимальное количество букв в отрезке
    s = input() ## сама строка длиной в _
    print(*max(spans(k, s), key=lambda p: p[0]))


main()
```

Comment: Действительно, вы доказали мне, что огромное множество задач можно свести к линейному времени. Благодарю